# How to run a command for every string in a JSON

Tags: python, json

This is my JSONstring:

```
[{'streamName': 'fsdfomsd_testsdfsdf.mp4', 'vodName': 'fsdfomsd_testsdfsdf.mp4', 'streamId': 'file', 'creationDate': 1642795502009, 'duration': -1, 'fileSize': 0, 'filePath': 'streams/047062868547026247609146.mp4', 'vodId': '047062868547026247609146', 'type': 'uploadedVod'}, {'streamName': 'lol69_testsdfsdf.mp4', 'vodName': 'lol69_testsdfsdf.mp4', 'streamId': 'file', 'creationDate': 1642795501986, 'duration': -1, 'fileSize': 0, 'filePath': 'streams/434226088820102862274153.mp4', 'vodId': '434226088820102862274153', 'type': 'uploadedVod'}, {'streamName': 'testmp_testsdfsdf.mp4', 'vodName': 'testmp_testsdfsdf.mp4', 'streamId': 'file', 'creationDate': 1642795501966, 'duration': -1, 'fileSize': 7, 'filePath': 'streams/476815150179587670305336.mp4', 'vodId': '476815150179587670305336', 'type': 'uploadedVod'}]
```

How would I run a command in Python for every vodId in the JSON? I am new to Python.

Comment: Why don't you start coding? Read the string using `json.loads`, then step your way through its structure.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Single quotes aren't allowed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So you have to extact all uniqe vodIds and after that you can run a function per vodId linke

```
vod_ids ={vod_id for d in your_json if (vod_id := d.get('vodId'))}
for vod_id in vod_ids:
    some_function(vod_id)
```

if your vod_ids don't have to be unique you can replace curly braces with braces which turns it from a set comprehension to a generator expression.

Comment: it works perfectly! you just misspelled vod_ods.

Comment: Changed. If that answers your question you can accept fhe answer and or vote it up.

Comment: Using a comprehension seems wrong, especially when you call `get` twice. You know you can add a separate default parameter to `get`?

Comment: I could also use a walrus here, it is also not super costly. I know I can put a default but I would rather not include some default value

Comment: The comprehension is due to extracting unique values only and in term oft a generator expression I think it is more readable.